# Missing ; before statement getJson issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, syntax, getjson

I have the following code:

```
function getWeather() {
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35& lon=139?jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data.id);
    });
}
```

And according to Firefox I'm getting a missing semicolon error in line 1:8

```
{"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},"sys":{"message":0.0106,"country":"JP","sunrise":1427920171,"sunset":1427965544},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"Sky is Clear","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":285.577,"temp_min":285.577,"temp_max":285.577,"pressure":1026.48,"sea_level":1034.31,"grnd_level":1026.48,"humidity":100},"wind":{"speed":5.56,"deg":57.001},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1427944893,"id":1851632,"name":"Shuzenji","cod":200}
```

I can't find the error.

Comment: I only get that error when I copy that JSON object into the Firefox console. If I put brackets `(` `)` around the object literal, it should be fine.

Comment: it looks valid json to me.

Comment: Your url implies the use of JSONP, while the content is apperently not a JSONP script. Which throws a syntax error when evaluated as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the said resource is expecting the callback param name as `callback` not as `jsonpcallback`

```
function getWeather() {
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3u1ff6p6/3/)

Also you can use CORS support

```
function getWeather() {
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3u1ff6p6/)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to run the code in Chrome's Developer Console does indeed give an error, although it's complaining about an unexpected colon `:` rather than a semi-colon `;`. It seems that jQuery is expecting JSONP in return. Checking the docs confirms that adding a parameter like, or similar to, `callback=?` prompts jQuery to interpret the result as JSONP but the result is plain old JSON.

Remove the `jsoncallback=?`.

On a different note, the link you have looks a little weird and seems to have too an extra question mark `?` and an extra space . You should also remove the extra characters too. Normally and ampersand `&` is used to separate request parameters.

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&% lon=139?jsoncallback=?
                                                       ^       ^
```

Using the following URL yields the results you expected

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139
```